# Finding a Bitmap contained inside another Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm using [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38619/Finding-a-Bitmap-contained-inside-another-Bitmap) to find a Bitmap inside another Bitmap, its working perfectly but I want to make it support transparency, that mean I want to search for a Bitmap which contains transparency inside another Bitmap. To clearify more, in this example I want to modify the code make it able to find the red dot (with transparency) inside the image :

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GphOG.png)

[The red dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vt5F.png)

Comment: You described a task, you did not ask a question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your bitmap must be 32bpp to support transparency. And in that example, you have only 3 bytes (RGB), in your case you need 4 bytes (RGBA). A means alpha for transparency. Then try to modify that code.

Comment: @x... I'll be gratefull if you can tell me how to a 32bpp Bitmap.

Comment: Take that code from codeproject, replace `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` with `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` and find factor `3` and replace it with `4`. That's all.

Comment: @x... I'm not the OP, but when you say "find factor 3 and replace it with 4",  are you saying to change all the instances of 3 to 4?

Comment: Junt replace number "3" with "4"

Comment: Thanks @x... , thare are some other modifications need to be done like checking if the Alpha channel is 0 ( mean transparent) or not, I'll post the code once I finish testing.